# Created word document using apache poi always open in compatibility mode

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, docx, compatibility-mode

I am trying to create word document using XWPF (POI-OOXML 3.16 ). The created word file opens in compatibility mode while using MS word 2016. Any solution? 
I don't want it to be appearing in compatibility mode.

Here is the simple code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException {
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

    try {
        File file = new File("path.docx");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        document.write(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        document.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Even though, I am not writing anything in the document, the created document (path.docx) opens in compatibility mode. I am using MS WORD 2016 on macbook pro.

Comment: I can imagine, that this is a mac based error. Can you share the document somewhere, so we on windows side can have a look ?

Comment: I tried to open the document in windows machine. It still says "compatibility mode" when viewed using latest office

Comment: can someone please help. I even ran the above program from windows machine. Still facing the same issue. It opens in compatibility mode

Comment: I have the same problem here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by creating an empty docx file using word and then used it to be modified from software